# I should've made an object, but when i try to control my object it lacks Attributes? Swampy

Tags: python, python-3.x, swampy

I have been following the instructions from my "think python" book (the version for 3.x), and I have done everything that the book told me, but I still get a weird error in one of the exercises?

Here's the problem:
I'm supposed to play around with the "TurtleWorld" from the module "swampy", and here's what I've got(this is exactly what is written in the book)

```
from TurtleWorld import *

world = TurtleWorld()
bob   = Turtle

print (bob)

fd(bob, 100)
lt(bob)
fd(bob, 100)

wait_for_user()
```

when I try to run this code it should start up a new program called TurtleWorld, where you should see a turtle move east and then north, leaving two line segments behind, but when I try to run the program I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\Lib\swampy-2.1.5\Polygon.py", line 8, in <module>
    fd(bob, 100)
  File "D:\Python34\Lib\swampy-2.1.5\TurtleWorld.py", line 179, in fd
    x, y = self.x, self.y
AttributeError: type object 'Turtle' has no attribute 'x'
```

This really weirds me out? I have, like I said, followed the book 100%.

By the way the book says this:

"The first line is a variation of the import statement we saw before; instead of creating a module object, it imports the functions from the module directly, so you can access them without using dot notation.

The next lines create a TurtleWorld assigned to world and a Turtle assigned to bob. Printing bob yields something like:

```
<TurtleWorld.Turtle object at 0x00FD1CD0>W
```

but when I use "print (bob)" I get this?

```
<class 'TurtleWorld.Turtle'>
```

I'll be happy to give any information you need to help me :)

Link to the online version of the book: http://faculty.stedwards.edu/mikek/python/thinkpython.pdf

page 47-48 is where this stuff is explained

Here's the link for the Swampy download:
http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/

I installed swampy by unzipping the "swampy" folder into the folder "libs", so the dir for the module looks like this now:

D:\Python34\Lib\swampy-2.1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Turtle` is a class where new `Turtle` objects are made from.

What you need is such a new object. You have to "call" the class to make a new object:

```
bob   = Turtle()
```

Comment: oh... well that was easy :) Thank you for you quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

bob should be instantiated as an object of `Turtle` class, rather than assigning the `Turtle` class to it.

Example -

```
bob   = Turtle()
```

Or

```
bob   = Turtle(world)
```